# Need to present a modal view immediately on app start-up, but it doesn't appear

Tags: iphone

There are times when my application needs to present a modal view immediately after start-up. I have a method on my main view controller *showEntryView* that presents the modal view successfully in response to a button press. I also call *showEntryView* when my main view controller receives *viewDidLoad*, but in this case the view does not appear.

Intuition suggests that I am trying to present the modal view too early--that I should present it sometime after receiving *viewDidLoad*. But when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intuition tells me that your modal view should probably be displaying itself in `-viewDidAppear` on your main view controller.  However, without further code, that's all I've got.

`-viewDidLoad` probably happens long before `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` -- particularly if it's defined as the Main Nib file in your plist -- and the application probably isn't in a very sane state at that point.  Allow your main view controller to appear, then present your modal...that means `-viewDidAppear` (or `-viewWillAppear`).

Comment: viewDidLoad worked great! I did have to add a flag to track whether I'd handled the first viewDidAppear so that I wouldn't present the modal view continuously (the modal view would close and my main controller would receive viewDidAppear again). A small price to pay.